# How to grep a specific integer in R?

Tags: r, integer

How to grep a specific integer in R ? I thought the parameter `fixed=TRUE` allowed to do that but apparently this is not the case:

```
NameDataTable = "LONG_TE_B.xpt"
NDie = 1
DataTable = read.xport(NameDataTable)
pos_DataTable_Die = grep(as.character(NDie), DataTable[,"DIEINDEX"], fixed=TRUE)
DataTableDie = DataTable[pos_DataTable_Die,]
```

That takes also the lines with DIEINDEX equal to 11. That is a problem for me :

```
> DataTableDie[947, "DIEINDEX"]
```

[1] 1

```
> DataTableDie[949, "DIEINDEX"]
```

[1] 11

How do I settle it, please ? Thank you in advance.

William

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can  `paste` the `^` and `$` to be more specific.  Or use the word boundary (`\\b`)

```
grep(paste0("^",NDie, "$"), DataTable[,"DIEINDEX"])
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of readability and a neat workflow it may be worthwhile to reflect on the solution offered by the [**`stringr`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package:

```
vals <- c("1", "11a", "DIEINDEX")
require(stringr)
str_detect(string = "1", pattern = vals)
```

## Results

As it can be inferred from the name, **`the str_detect`** function detects existence of a string. In this context the function would produce:

```
> str_detect(string = "1", pattern = vals)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

### `as.numeirc()`

Does not cause any difficulties

```
str_detect(string = 1, pattern = vals)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that works ! I just did :

```
DataTable = read.xport(NameDataTable)
for(i in 1:nrow(DataTable)){
  DataTable[i,"DIEINDEX"] = paste0("^",as.character(DataTable[i,"DIEINDEX"]),"$")
}
pos_DataTable_Die = grep(paste0("^",as.character(NDie),"$"), DataTable[,"DIEINDEX"], fixed=TRUE)
DataTableDie = DataTable[pos_DataTable_Die,]
```